# Dealing with NULL date ( 0001-01-01 10:30:00 AM)

Tags: linq, sharepoint-2013, wcf-data-services

I have a SharePoint workflow that is calling a WebService to update SQL table. 
One of the items to update is a completion date. If I pass it as a datetime to the WCF service, I get a BADRequest. I managed to get the update to work if I send the date as string, and then use the `Convert.ToDatetime` during my LINQ update functions.

The issue I have is that if the date is empty, I get the classic 0001-01-01 10:30:00 AM date value. 
I have tried the following command to use NULL value.

```
jcent.JobDateCompleted = string.IsNullOrEmpty(job.stringJobDateCompleted) 
      ? (DateTime ?) null
      : Convert.ToDateTime(job.stringJobDateCompleted);
```

but is does not work:

Any idea how I can achieve this ?

Note: I have set all dates be Nullable

Comment: Is `JobDateCompleted` nullable in the database?

Comment: Your question is tagged `sharepoint-2013` - what does this have to do with SharePoint?

Comment: The Web Call is done via a SharePoint 2013 workflow, that  reads the Date from a list item, and passes it into a parameter.